# How to convert list string to specific object

Tags: c#, dynamic, compiler-construction, eval

I have a list of strings that is sent by javascript.

```
List<string> options = new List<string>()
        {
            {"new MeuObjeto(\"teste 1\", 10, 12, 50, 70, 0, new System.Drawing.Font(\"Arial\", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point), System.Drawing.Color.Black, false)"},
            {"new MeuObjeto(\"teste 2\", 10, 14, 50, 70, 0, new System.Drawing.Font(\"Arial\", 14, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point), System.Drawing.Color.Black, false)"},
            {"new MeuObjeto(\"teste 3\", 10, 16, 50, 70, 0, new System.Drawing.Font(\"Arial\", 35, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point), System.Drawing.Color.Black, false)"},
            {"new MeuObjeto(\"teste 4\", 10, 18, 50, 70, 0, new System.Drawing.Font(\"Arial\", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point), System.Drawing.Color.Black, false)"},
            {"new MeuObjeto(\"teste 5\", 10, 20, 50, 70, 0, new System.Drawing.Font(\"Arial\", 9, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point), System.Drawing.Color.Black, false)"},
            {"new MeuObjeto(\"teste 6\", 10, 22, 50, 70, 0, new System.Drawing.Font(\"Arial\", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point), System.Drawing.Color.Black, false)"}
        };
```

How to convert this data to the object (MeuObjeto)?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to compile and execute C# code from strings like this. You absolutely do not want to do this though as it would open up the biggest possible security hole in your server as it would dutifully compile and execute anything sent to it.

Instead, you should just send data and write code to create instances of `MeuObjeto` from that data.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how can I do that you commented to dynamically compile?